# nativescript 4.2. Error while building android app with release flag

Tags: javascript, android, telerik, nativescript

I've done some app for IOS and Android.

IOS is working fine and it's poblished on App store since 3 weeks.
So, the time has come for android. I have to do some css tweaks, beacuse android was looking different in some aspects.

After when i did it, i run tns run android, next emulator appear.
All is working well, so i've run tests on Firebase console.

It was a suprise for me, beacuse i saw this error: (Emulator installed is launching app without issues.)

Nativescript fails to load code that holds common js functions.

[image]

Here is part of my app.js

[image]

And, right now i'm able to see this error in my emulator.
Steps to reproduce:
- run tns run android (app is working well)
- do some typo in any js file (make any error): livesync will run again, and as result i will see this error.

My question is: do android have problems with requiring this file? IOS is working very well, but i'm unable to deploy android.

Thank you.

Comment: Try removing the `.js` in the path. It supposed to work still but give that a try.

Comment: Hi @Manoj, i think the issue was _common. I've used common as name and seems it works well, i will double check and confirm. Cheers.